# Sundial shadow tip locus

Tags: geometry, spherical-trigonometry

Assume a pole height h << R (radius of earth) erected at a point (long/lat $ =\theta,\phi).$

Depending on given time of day and month, is there a formula for shadow tip locus on ground (tangent plane)? We can make the most basic simplifying assumptions. Is the curve  at 45$^0$ latitude  more near to a conic ?

Comment: No, not a conic curve, but a "8-shaped curve" ; see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_time)

Comment: @JeanMarie The analemma is the locus described by the position in the sky of the sun at midday during a year. I think the OP is rather referring to the path described by the shadow tip during a day.

Comment: @JeamMarie Yes, I asked about an assembly of the 365 daily/diurnal loci or 52 weekly loci or 12 monthly loci or at the least 4 during ap/pri helions & two solistices

Comment: @Aretino Yes for the day, you are completely right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line connecting the Sun with the Earth center describes a cone in a frame which is rotating with the Earth (we may neglect the relative motion of Earth and Sun during the short timespan of a day).

The same cone is described by the line connecting the Sun with the tip of your pole (because the Sun is very far away). The shadow of the tip is then located on the intersection between that cone and a plane (the ground), so it is by definition a conic section, usually a hyperbola.

That hyperbola changes slightly day after day, due to the relative motions of Earth and Sun.

[image]

EDIT

Set up a coordinate system on the ground, with the pole of length $h$ at the origin and the $x$-axis directed due North. The latitude $\theta$ is also the angle formed by the direction of the Earth rotation axis with the positive direction of the $x$-axis (I'm assuming we are in the North hemisphere, see the above diagram).

Suppose that at midday, when the Sun is due South, its direction forms an angle $\varphi$ with the negative direction of the $x$-axis. This angle of course changes day by day. Then the locus of the shadow tip is the hyperbola given by the equation
$$
{(x-x_0)^2\over a^2}-{y^2\over b^2}=1,
$$
where $a$, $b$ and $x_0$ can be found after some computation to be the following:
$$
a={h\over2}\big(\cot\theta+\cot(2\varphi+\theta)\big),\quad
b^2=a^2\cos^2\varphi \big(\tan^2(\varphi+\theta)-\tan^2\varphi\big),
$$
$$
x_0={h\over2}\big(\cot\theta-\cot(2\varphi+\theta)\big).
$$

Comment: Can we have plots? it would serve as a crude clock, but just for curiosity..

Comment: I've prepared a GeoGebra file that should show you the whole thing: see https://www.geogebra.org/material/show/id/AHEgBVUd .

Comment: See also my edited answer.

Comment: No problem me too in the Northern hemisphere. In worksheet of GeoGebra only sliders appear without a plot although your other geometric demos work.

Comment: You probably have an old version of GeoGebra: update to GeoGebra5, which has 3D tools.

Comment: φ = 90 - θ + (sun declination) Is this correct?

Comment: @JB0x2D1 No, $\varphi$ is the altitude of the Sun above the horizon, at local noon on a certain day. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_coordinate_system

Comment: @Intelligentipauca How is this angle properly calculated?

Comment: @JB0x2D1 https://sciencing.com/many-hours-daylight-summer-8196183.html

Comment: https://sciencing.com/calculate-suns-altitude-8556649.html

Answer (score 0):

$L$: Latitude

$d$: Declination of the sun

$h$: height of the vertical pole

The equation:

$$(y\cos L-h \sin L)^2=(x^2+y^2+h^2) (\sin d)^2$$

Or

$$k=\cos(L+d) \cos (L-d)$$
$$a=h\cos d/\sqrt{k}$$
$$b=h\sin d \cos d/k$$
$$c=h\sin L \cos L/k$$

$$(y-c)^2/b^2-x^2/a^2=1$$

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).